Two DragTarget side by side loose the onLeave Event
I have this code below for two dragTargets side by side.
return DragTarget(
builder: (
BuildContext context,
List accepted,
List rejected,
) {
return Container(
height: size.height,
width: size.width,
color: normalArea,
);
},
  //when enter in the drop area dragging something
  onWillAcceptWithDetails: (DragTargetDetails<int> details) {
    setState(() {
      normalArea = Colors.red; 
    });
    return true;
  },

  //when drag happens
  onAcceptWithDetails: (DragTargetDetails<int> details) {
    setState(() {
      print('dropped');
      normalArea = Colors.blue;
    });
  },

  onLeave: (data) {
    print('onLeave');
    setState(() {
      normalArea = Colors.blue;
    });
  },
);

The normalArea  is just a
Color? normalArea = Colors.transparent;
So the idea is when we enter dragguing some container for instance, over one dragtarget ,it will change the color to red and when we leave it change to blue.
The problem is that when we leave it direct to another dragTarget the onLeave wont work. It is called but, since in the same time we enter in another dragTarget calling the onWillAcceptWithDetails so is like the setState() is called just once and not one for the onLeave and another to onWillAcceptWithDetails.
What you think? Any sugestion do deal with it?
Thank you
I tried to put a Container between the two dragTargets but even with it, if we move the mouse quickly dragguing somenthing it will skip this divider and we keep losing the onLeave event.
I guess that we can implement a List<> and to create a class with a Color and the Drop widget and maybe that could be a good solution. I am trying to know about others ideas nd sugestions.

so you want it to be red only within the first drag target? if so, what about the second drag target? what should happen if you drag over the second drag target?

The behaviour need to be the same for both...The behaviour is: When we enter dragguing something over dragTarget it will be red. When we leave the dragTarget it will be blue. I create this only to demonstrate the idea.
So the expected behaviour for two dragTargets side by side: I enter dragguing something over the first one. The color of this dragTarget will be red now. I keep dragguing crossing the entire first one dragTarget to the second dragTarget. When I enter in the second, the color of the first need to change to blue and in the second to red.

Holly molly, this is look like a very good solution. I will try to implement and give you a feedback. The approach is different and not only solve the issue, but teach us a lot. Sorry my english and thank you!

sure, your welcome, have fun learning ;-) note that you dont have 3 ValueListenableBuilders - you can do that with 3 normal StatefulWidgets as well

I tried your code...And works like charm. Thank you again.
